# How do you move infoboxes to the side?

Tags: templates, mediawiki, wikipedia, infobox

I just imported infobox templates from Wikipedia. They're working nicely, but I'm having a bit of trouble.

I've added the Infobox person template to a number of pages on my wiki. It looks and works fine, but **I cannot get it to move to the right side of the screen**. I have visual editor and I can use it to grab it, but I can only drag it above or below my text.

Any help would be immensely appreciated, I'm sort of fumbling about in the dark here.

I'm using master with xampp.

> *I don't know anything about programming or computer science, so please bear with me, I'm a writer creating a wiki for my fictional world.*

Answer (score 1):

The infoboxes are styled with CSS. You can find the styles related to infoboxes by searching for `.infobox` in https://w.wiki/aGk. After you have located the relevant lines, you can put them in the MediaWiki:Common.css page in your own wiki.

In the end, your MediaWiki:Common.css should look something like this:

```css
.infobox .navbar {
    font-size: 100%;
}

.infobox {
    border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
    border-spacing: 3px;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    color: black;
    /* @noflip */
    margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em;
    padding: 0.2em;
    /* @noflip */
    float: right;
    /* @noflip */
    clear: right;
    font-size: 88%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
/* etc. you could also add more .infobox related styles here */
```

above css extracted from the Wikipedia page ["MediaWiki:Common.css"](https://w.wiki/aGk), which is released under the [Creative Commons Attribution-Share-Alike License 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).